# Can't get a class create with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, conditional-statements

I made an increment class on scroll with jquery and now i want to get it in a condition but it doesn't work, where is the problem?

this is my code:

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
      count--
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if (scrollable > count) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      count++
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }

ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

so i want to make a condition like:

```js
if ( $( 'ul li:nth-child(2)' ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {
 alert('is second');
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what this condition should check.

Comment: it should check if my second 'li' has the class 'active'

Comment: You want to perform this check each time you scroll?

Comment: My goal is to create a class (is-one) on the 'ul' when the first 'li' has the class 'active' and do it for each 'li' like (ul hasclass is-second when second li hasclass active, ul hasclass is-third when third li hasclass active ……)